# ActiveMq raised javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException when using the statistics plugin

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am currently trying to retrieve statistics from ActiveMQ. I use ActiveMQ 5.11.1 and I added the statisticsBrokerPlugin to the config file. As it is specified here:http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html, I'm sending an empty message to ActiveMQ.Statistics.Subscription to retrieve all queue and topic subscriptions.

When running it, most of the time an error will be raised when sending the message. Something like:

`Caused by: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost,destinationType=Queue,destinationName=prod.import.csv,endpoint=Consumer,clientId=ID_tadpole-import-5-38631-1438235942638-2_17,consumerId=ID_tadpole-import-5-38631-1438235942638-3_17_1_14503`

Here is the useful part of the code:

```
val factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(activeMQConn)
factory.setWatchTopicAdvisories(false)
val connection = factory.createConnection()
connection.start()

val session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
val replyTo = session.createTemporaryQueue()
val consumer = session.createConsumer(replyTo)
val queueName = "ActiveMQ.Statistics.Subscription"
val testQueue = session.createQueue(queueName)
val producer = session.createProducer(testQueue)
val msg = session.createMessage()
msg.setJMSReplyTo(replyTo)
producer.send(msg) // this will trigger the error
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Thanks

PS:

- Our system is handling hundreds of list and thousands of messages
- It does not fail all the time, maybe 90% of times.
- The destinationName & consumerId seems to be changing frequently.
- I don't see any error on in activemq's log.

Here the stacktrace:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: null
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:54)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1420)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1346)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.send(ActiveMQSession.java:1904)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:288)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:223)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducerSupport.send(ActiveMQMessageProducerSupport.java:241)
        at com.fliptop.common.metrics.activemq.ActiveMQStatistics.com$fliptop$common$metrics$activemq$ActiveMQStatistics$$recurringFetch$1(ActiveMQStatistics.scala:75)
        at com.fliptop.common.metrics.activemq.ActiveMQStatistics$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(ActiveMQStatistics.scala:113)
        at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$5.run(Scheduler.scala:79)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$2$$anon$1.run(Scheduler.scala:242)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:401)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: null
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getDestinationName(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.activemq.plugin.StatisticsBroker.prepareSubscriptionMessage(StatisticsBroker.java:241)
        at org.apache.activemq.plugin.StatisticsBroker.sendSubStats(StatisticsBroker.java:231)
        at org.apache.activemq.plugin.StatisticsBroker.send(StatisticsBroker.java:143)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.send(MutableBrokerFilter.java:157)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processMessage(TransportConnection.java:541)
        at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage.visit(ActiveMQMessage.java:768)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:334)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:188)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:113)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:270)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:214)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost,destinationType=Queue,destinationName=prod.import.opportunity,endpoint=Consumer,clientId=ID_tadpole-import-1-40652-1438591283770-2_16,consumerId=ID_tadpole-import-1-40652-1438591283770-3_16_1_35720
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1095)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:643)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:678)
        at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:267)
        ... 16 more
```

Comment: I don't see any issues with your code, its running perfectly on my local machine. and what are you passing to ActiveMQConnectionFactory

Comment: activeMQConn is the broker url. See post edit for the rest.

Comment: Could you post please the first few lines of the stacktrace when the error occurs.

Comment: @SubOptimal just added it to my post. Thanks

Comment: @MarcSimon Could you set the logging level for class `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection` to `trace`. Maybe it tries to send a package to an already closed connection. In the source at line 1416 there is following statement `LOG.debug("Received an exception but connection is closing");`